# Filter a combobox in a datagrid based on another combobox column in the same row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am new to wpf and i want to know how can i implement 2 comboboxes columns in a datagrid where the first combobox contains Countries ,and the other contains cities so while editing on datagrid cities colunmn combobox is filtered by the country selected in countries combo box using MVVM pattern

Thanks

Comment: i have tried the below but it doesnt work :).i would prefer u providing an example.

Comment: If it doesnt work for you, then ask me. Dont wait for other answers untill one will work for you! I'm 100% sure this will work when implemented correctly.

Comment: ur code gives an error as IEnumerable<City> Cities is a readonly property it doesnt have set so when selecting a city from cities combobox it gives an error

Comment: Of course you need another property to bind the `SelectedItem` of your Cities ComboBox to. Something like `public City SelectedCity`

Comment: plz try ur not working code then reply ,,the city collection binded to the combobox must has set property . i tried to add the selectedCity and bind it to selectedItem of city combobox and gives the same error

Comment: another note lets say that i selected USA from country combobox in the first row then the cities combobox will be filtered to cities USA not for the first row only but for all rows and thats is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible, the easiest way is to let your ViewModel do the filtering:

```
public class Data:ModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Countries { get; set; }
    private List<City> _allCities = new List<City>();

    public IEnumerable<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedCountry == null)
                return _allCities;

            return _allCities.Where(c => c.Country == _selectedCountry);
        }

    }

    public Data()
    {
        Countries = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        //Fill _allCities and Countries here
    }

    private string _selectedCountry;
    public string SelectedCountry
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCountry;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedCountry != value)
            {
                _selectedCountry = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
                OnPropertyChanged("Cities");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class City
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you bind your DataGrid to a collection of your Data-class. The ItemsSource of your Country-ComboBoy is bound to Countries, the one from your Cities-ComboBoy is bound to Cities and the SelectedItem of your Country-CB is bound to your SelectedCountry (Mode=TwoWay).